# How I could use ruby for print first line?

Tags: ruby, linux

Im using this command but not works

```
convert capchas4 -define connected-components:verbose=true -connected-components -4 -auto-level ccredsult.png \
  | ruby -a -F' ' -ne 'puts $F[3]' \
  | ruby -a -F'' -ne 'puts $F[0].split(/\n/)[1]'
```

the insput of this command is

```
  0: 100x50+0+0 51.0,25.2 4019 srgba(251,254,252,0)
  1: 28x22+39+9 51.1,19.1 353 srgba(0,0,0,1)
  3: 19x22+68+12 74.3,21.3 225 srgba(0,0,0,1)
  4: 15x23+5+13 10.0,24.7 211 srgba(0,0,0,1)
  2: 15x24+22+10 28.7,22.6 192 srgba(0,0,0,1)
```

and output is this

```
100x50+0+0
28x22+39+9
19x22+68+12
15x23+5+13
15x24+22+10
```

I expected this output

```
    100x50+0+0
```

how I could solve this 
Please help me

Comment: Please review and improve the formatting and wording of your question. Stack Overflow is an online reference site, and readability and understandability of the question is extremely important. If English isn't your primary language it might help to have a peer who is familiar with the problem and who speaks English also work with you. Jon Skeet's "[Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)" would be a good page to read.

Comment: Where does `centroid` come from? It's not in your input anywhere.

Comment: If you just want to process the first line of the output, pipe it through `head -1`

Comment: Instead of doing crazy one-liners, why not make a proper Ruby script and just run that?

Comment: centroid ; this maybe a error

Comment: I dont have head command

Comment: I think could be solved using ruby command for replace newlines  by string and use this command          ruby -a -F'string' -ne 'puts $F[1]'

Comment: but i dont know how i could replace  newlines in ruby

Comment: Why don't you have the `head` command? `head` and `tail` are core parts of the OS in Linux. They're used extensively. You're doing a lot of work that you should be able to easily do using `awk` also. `head -1 | awk '{print $1}'` should be close as `awk` is also extensively used by Linix. It won't work without `head` and `awk`.

Comment: yes but Im trying to use ruby for easy export to other OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command-line is doing a lot it doesn't need to. Try this:

```
echo '0: 100x50+0+0 51.0,25.2 4019 srgba(251,254,252,0)' | ruby -e 'puts ARGF.readline.split[3]'
```

Which outputs:

```
4019
```

You could use that Ruby line instead of your attempt.

If your data is in a file, or to test with more data:

```
cat > ~/Desktop/test.txt
0: 100x50+0+0 51.0,25.2 4019 srgba(251,254,252,0)
1: 28x22+39+9 51.1,19.1 353 srgba(0,0,0,1)
3: 19x22+68+12 74.3,21.3 225 srgba(0,0,0,1)
4: 15x23+5+13 10.0,24.7 211 srgba(0,0,0,1)
2: 15x24+22+10 28.7,22.6 192 srgba(0,0,0,1)
```

Then, piping the data into Ruby:

```
ruby -e 'puts ARGF.readline.split[3]' < ~/Desktop/test.txt
```

outputs:

```
4019
```

Read the documentation on [`ARGF`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/ARGF.html), [`ARGF.readline`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/ARGF.html#method-i-readline) and [`split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-split)
 to understand what it's doing.